# setInverval lagging behind, and Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, timer

This is the code that I deployed on Heroku. It's function is to update a certain key that i'm displaying every ten seconds.

```
const express = require('express');
const timestamp = require('time-stamp');
var app = express();
var port = 3000;

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    console.log(`Listening at port: ${port}`);
});

app.get("/", encr)
code = 5

function encr(req, res){
 console.log(`Code accessed, code = ${code}`)
 res.send({code})
}


setInterval(async function() {
  code = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  console.log(`Key updated. Time: ${timestamp.utc('DD/mm:ss:ms')}`)
}, 10 * 1000);
```

This `setInterval` function needs to run every 10 seconds, but ends up running every 10.01 seconds, which after a bit begins to add up.
Logs:

```
2021-02-08T20:15:45.414054+00:00 app[web.1]: Key updated. Time: 08/15:45:413
2021-02-08T20:15:55.423763+00:00 app[web.1]: Key updated. Time: 08/15:55:423
```

[...]

```
2021-02-08T20:18:25.543898+00:00 app[web.1]: Key updated. Time: 08/18:25:543
2021-02-08T20:18:35.551720+00:00 app[web.1]: Key updated. Time: 08/18:35:551
2021-02-08T20:18:45.559856+00:00 app[web.1]: Key updated. Time: 08/18:45:559
```

How can I fix this so it's exactly 10 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeouts/intervals aren't entirely accurate at the millisecond timescale. Instead of trying to reassign `code` every precise interval, consider instead saving the timestamp whenever `code` gets updated, and when it gets accessed again, check whether the timestamp has expired - if so, reassign it:

```
const makeCode = () => {
  code = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  lastAssignTimestamp = performance.now();
};
let lastAssignTimestamp;
let code;
makeCode();

function encr(req, res){
  if (performance.now() - lastAssignTimestamp > 10_000) {
    // then the code has expired...
    makeCode();
  }
  console.log(`Code accessed, code = ${code}`)
  res.send({code})
}
```

Comment: I've just checked, and apparently even though the print says it's building up a lag, it's actually floating around the same time; So it's not a problem.

I'll keep it running throughout the entire night and see if the result is good or bad when I wake up, and i'll update here.

Then i'll check your solution and see if that works better.

Cheers

Comment: Update: It indeed does drift after a couple of hours, which is no good. Before asking this question I thought of doing something like this with timestamps, but wasn't sure of the approach. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I've edited my code to also print the last update's timestamp, that way I can just check directly in my other code without time keeping shenanigans

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 3000;

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    console.log(`Listening at port: ${port}`);
});

app.get("/", encr)
code = 5
last_time = 0

const makeCode = () => {
  code = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  lastAssignTimestamp = +new Date()
  console.log(`New Code: ${code}`)
};
let lastAssignTimestamp;

makeCode();
setInterval(function(){
  let x = +new Date()
  if (x - lastAssignTimestamp > 1000 * 60){
    // then the code has expired... every minute
    makeCode();
  }
  last_time = lastAssignTimestamp
  console.log(`Time left till next update: ${Math.round(((1000 * 60) - (x - lastAssignTimestamp))/1000)}`)

}, 1000);


function encr(req, res){
  res.send(
    {code, last_time}
  )
}
```